# Two questions on Let $A ∈ R^{n×n}, B ∈ R^{n×m}, C ∈ R^{m×n}, and D ∈ R^{m×m}$. ...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm working on my Linear Algebra and came across this question:

Let $A ∈ R^{n×n}, B ∈ R^{n×m}, C ∈ R^{m×n}, and D ∈ R^{m×m}$.

Show that if $A, D − CA^{−1}B$ , and  $D$  are
nonsingular, then $A − BD^{−1}C$ is nonsingular,

and

$(A − BD^{−1}C)^{−1}$= $A^{−1} + A^{−1}B(D − CA^{−1}B)^{−1}CA^{−1}$

Can someone help me to approach this question? I dont really know how to start..

Comment: Multiply $A - BD^{-1}C$ with the right hand side and prove that the result is $1$. This is not difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider the $(n+m)\times (n+m)$-matrix

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\ C & D
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

The idea is to act as if we have a $2\times 2$-matrix $ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} $  and eliminate $c$ (or $b$).

Sketch of a solution:

1. Regarding singularity, use the fact that $\det\begin{pmatrix}
   A & B \\ 0 & D
   \end{pmatrix} = \det(A)\det(D) = \det\begin{pmatrix}
   A & 0 \\ C & D
   \end{pmatrix}$.
2. You may know how to invert 2x2-matrices via Cramer's rule.
   Here's a special case where the lower-left entry $c=0$:
   $$ \begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ 0&d \end{pmatrix}^{-1} =
        \frac{1}{ad}\begin{pmatrix} d & -b \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix} =
        \begin{pmatrix} a^{-1} & -a^{-1}bd^{-1} \\ 0 & d^{-1} \end{pmatrix} $$
   Note that I sandwiched $b$ between $a$ and $d$, because we are going to replace these numbers by matrices! You can verify

   $$ \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & D \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
      = \begin{pmatrix} A^{-1} & -A^{-1}BD^{-1} \\ 0 & D^{-1} \end{pmatrix} $$
3. In the 2x2-case you can apply Gaussian elimination to eliminate $c$ (or similarly $b$). Here it is important that all operations used in Gaussian elimination can be done via matrix multiplication from the right:
   $$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -bd^{-1} \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}
   = \begin{pmatrix} a - bd^{-1}c & 0 \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix} $$
   This suggests that
   $$ \begin{pmatrix} I_n & -BD^{-1} \\ 0 & I_m \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix} A&B\\C&D \end{pmatrix}
   = \begin{pmatrix} A - BD^{-1}C & 0 \\ C & D \end{pmatrix} $$
   and thus we can write the inverse like so:
   $$ 
   \begin{pmatrix} A&B\\C&D \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
   = \begin{pmatrix} A - BD^{-1}C & 0 \\ C & D \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
   \begin{pmatrix} I_n & -BD^{-1} \\ 0 & I_m \end{pmatrix}
   =: M_B
    $$
   Compute $M_B$ using an analogous version of the matrix-inversion formula we derived in point 2.
4. Now we computed the inverse $M_B$ by eliminating $B$. We could have eliminated $C$ instead which also leads to an inverse $M_C$.
   As inverses are unique $M_B = M_C$. Compare the entries!